# Rails 3.2 - form erroneously submitted multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the model Box, and each Box has many box_videos (another model).  I want the user to be able to add box_videos to the box, so I created the following edit form for that (after creation of @box):

```
<%= form_tag "/box_videos", { method: :post, id: "new_box_videos", remote: true } do %>
    <%= text_field_tag "box_videos[][link]", '' %>
    <%= text_area_tag "box_videos[][description]", '' %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag("box_videos[][box_id]", @box.id) %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag("box_videos[][user_id]", current_user.id) %>

    <div class="another_video">Add Another Video</div>
    <%= submit_tag "Save Videos" %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(@box) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :size %>
    <%= f.text_field :all_other_attributes %>

    <%= f.submit "Create Box" %>
<% end %>
```

And some Javascript to facilitate adding more box_videos in one click.

```
<script>
$('.another_video').click(function() {
  $('#new_box_videos').prepend('<input id="box_videos_link" name="box_videos[][link]" placeholder="Link to a youtube video." style="width: 18em;" type="text" value=""><textarea id="box_videos_description" name="box_videos[][description]" placeholder="Describe this video." style="width: 18em;"></textarea><br/><br/><input id="box_videos_box_id" name="box_videos[][box_id]" type="hidden" value="' + gon.box_id.toString() + '"><input id="box_videos_user_id" name="box_videos[][user_id]" type="hidden" value="' + gon.user_id.toString() + '">');
});
</script>
```

The above code works, in that `params[:box_videos]`  when submitting three box_videos is as follows:

```
[{"link"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=dpAP8bq3ddU
", "description"=>"foo", "box_id"=>"63", "user_id"=>"16"}, {"link"=>"https
://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=dpAP8bq3ddU", "description"
=>"bar", "box_id"=>"63", "user_id"=>"16"}, {"link"=>"https://www.you
tube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=dpAP8bq3ddU", "description"=>"hello world",
"box_id"=>"63", "user_id"=>"16"}]
```

In my controller I would just create a box_video object for every hash in the array and it works out just fine.  BUT the problem comes when each time I submit the nested form_tag form, I send multiple requests to the controller action!  Which means there are duplicates being created.

I can think of adding logic to the box_videos controller create action to check for duplicate content, but it seems rather hacky.  Can anyone please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: This is because every time you submit the form, it's sending _everything_ over and over again. Honestly, I think nested forms is really the way to go. There are a bunch of tutorials online on how to do that in an elegant way.

Comment: yes that is the observed the behavior, but any thoughts on why everything is sent over and over again?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have nested form elements according to the html spec ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379622/1630540)).

You might want to use [nested forms](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) for this, it provides the creation of associated models via jquery with useful form_helper wrappers.

Comment: actually they're not nested, sorry about the mistake and I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: For safety, you should set the user in your controller to current_user, people can inspect the page and change the user_id.

Comment: okay, thanks for the heads up! is there anything else that's wrong with the form though?

Comment: Is rails_ujs included twice? That usually generates this sort of behaviour.

Comment: hmm how would I check that? I only see jquery_ujs.js in my page source

Comment: That's the way, you might also have some old compiled assets which you can remove with `rake assets:clean`